# Which reaction is most likely to take place in a voltaic cell?

Tags: redox

I was confused by this MCQ:

[image]

The answer is A. I thought that the spontaneous reaction was usually between the most negative and least negative. Could someone please explain why this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to remember that for a formal redox half-reaction, oxidizing H2 to H+,
there is relation of the standard reaction Gibbs energy and  the standard redox potential

$$\Delta_r G^\circ =  -nFE^\circ .$$

The lower is the potential, the stronger(thermodynamically, not necessarily kinetically) is the respective reductant and weaker the oxidant. And vice versa.

So $\ce{Mn(s)}$ is the strongest reductant,  $\ce{Pb(s)}$ the weakest one.

So $\ce{Mn^2+(aq)}$ is the weakest oxidant, $\ce{Pb^2+(aq)}$ the strongest one.

From above must be clear that the only spontaneous reaction is :

$$\ce{Mn(s) + Fe^2+(aq) -> Mn^2+(aq) + Fe(s)}$$

Comment: Thank you! However, it says that the answer is A, That's why I'm confused. Is it because this reaction is.not in the options?

Comment: Sorry, I have confused metals, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also state that, when comparing two redox couples, the metal belonging to the redox couple with the most negative values will react. Here, comparing the three metals $\ce{Mn, Fe, Pb}$, the metallic $\ce{Mn}$ will always react and produce $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$, because of its highest negative value ($E° = - 1.18$ V) and $\ce{Pb}$ will never react: its redox potential is not negative enough.

Answer (score -1):

One of the easiest ways is to draw the reactions in the direction they occur.  For example, considering:

> $$\ce{Mn + Fe++ ->  Mn++  + Fe}$$

$$\ce{Mn++ + 2e-  -> Mn    - 1.18 V Does not want 2 electrons}$$

Can be viewed as:

$$\ce{Mn  -> Mn++ + 2e-                + 1.18 V glad to give them away}$$

$$\ce{Fe++ + 2e- -> Fe.           - 0.45 V happy without electrons, but not as much as Mn}$$

Then just add:     1.18 + (-0.45) = + 0.73 V positive, it will occur spontaneously.  Electrons flow toward Fe++.

Do this with all the others, only A is positive.  The sign (positive or negative) of the *sum* of the 2 half reactions shows whether or not it is spontaneous.  This is how batteries work.

Most importantly, direction of electron flow is *relative* to the to metals involved, with most positive to most negative (as written!) producing the highest voltage.

Comment: Sign changing of electrode potentials is something which is disliked by electrochemists. Please search previous discussions on this topic. The sign of the electrode potential is invariant.

Comment: @AChem I have heard this, but it is a very valuable tool for this specific purpose.  + favorable ... - unfavorable.  Writing out the half reactions **in the direction they run** and simply summing makes it easy.  Try it!

Comment: I often compare it to marking left/right river bank naively (on my left/right) or cartografically (on my left/right when looking downstream.) Similarly, marking cathodes/anodes where reduction/oxidation occurs(Phys chem.) vs  where reduction/oxidation occur when in active galvanic mode (engineers at design of rechargable cells.) // For potentials, it is unlucky they did not established different formal electrochemical quantities. Perhaps using dual-sign redox potential versus single sign electrode potential. Having flipped signs may confuse many beginners, when confusing both.

Comment: @Poutnik points very well taken.  Downhill and uphill?  But I am more into mechanism than math, which is why half reactions are done first.  Rote and rhyme failing, Al metal gives, atomic chlorine takes.

Comment: Potentials (not limited to electrochemistry) should have IMHO a single sign, as property of a state, not direction of a process. The flipping nature of redox potentials is abusing of general terminology, unfortunately already burned into foundations of electrochemistry.

Comment: Use what works, but yes, certainly be aware.  I suppose the convention could be to always write it from the 0 charge state.

Comment: Thank you. It's a lot clearer now.